# addEventListener click function does not work

Tags: javascript, html

I needed to save an html table's content in a .txt file. So I found this example:

**page.html:**

```
<html>
<body>
    <div>
        <textarea id="textbox">Type something here</textarea> 
        <button id="create">Create file</button> 
        <a download="info.txt" id="downloadlink" style="display: none">Download</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

**create.js:**

```
(function () {
var textFile = null,
  makeTextFile = function (text) {
    var data = new Blob([text], {type: 'text/plain'});

     if (textFile !== null) {
     window.URL.revokeObjectURL(textFile);
    }

    textFile = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);

    return textFile;
  };

  var create = document.getElementById('create'),
  textbox = document.getElementById('textbox');

  create.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var link = document.getElementById('downloadlink');
    link.href = makeTextFile(textbox.value);
    link.style.display = 'block';
  }, false);
})();
```

This code has a text area. When you click the botton it creates a "Download" link and by clicking it you can download the text area content as a txt file.

I am trying to implement a very similar function. Only difference is I get my string from an html table. Here is the code:

**html:**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row" style="">
    <section class="module span12" style="top: 50px">
        <div class="module-body">
            <button type="button" class="btn-blue"
                style="top: 80px; right: 130px;" onclick="loadOutputs()">Load
                Outputs</button>
            <button class="btn btn-blue" id="save" onclick="createText()"
                style="top: 80px; right: 130px;">Save</button>
            <a download="info.txt" id="downloadlink" style="display: block">Download</a>
            <div id="loadingElement" class="loaded">
                <table>
                    <tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<div class="row"></div>
```

**javascript:**

```
function createText() {

    var text = '';
    var table = document.getElementById("tbody");
    if (table) {
        for ( var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
            text = text.concat(row.innerText);
            }
    }

    var textFile = null, makeTextFile = function(text) {

        var data = new Blob([text], {type: 'text/plain'});
        if (textFile !== null) {
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(textFile);
        }

        textFile = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
        return textFile;
    };

    var create = document.getElementById('save');

    create.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var link = document.getElementById('downloadlink');
        link.href = makeTextFile(text);
        link.style.display = 'block';
    }, false);
}
```

In the js code, when I debug, I see that it successfully fills the text variable with the contents of the table, but cannot get into create.addEventListener().

Inside the function variable link seems to be 'undefined', so I make the assumption that it cannot get inside of the function. What might be the problem?

Comment: where did you load the script???

Comment: @ArunPJohny the table is created by a javascript function

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal the script is loaded from a parent html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is, you have a function called `createText` which is having all your code including the save handler... then your button's `onclick` attribute is calling the `createText` function....

In the above working sample the actual code is in a IIFE block which is executed on page load... so you need to either use a IIFE or call the function `createText` on page load and remove `onclick="createText()"` from the button since the actual click handler is registered using script. so

```js
(function(){
    
    var textFile = null,
        makeTextFile = function (text) {
            
            var data = new Blob([text], {
                type: 'text/plain'
            });
            if (textFile !== null) {
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(textFile);
            }
            
            textFile = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
            return textFile;
        };
    
    var create = document.getElementById('save');
    
    create.addEventListener('click', function () {
        var text = '';
        var table = document.getElementById("tbody");
        if (table) {
            for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
                console.log('a')
                text = text.concat(row.innerText);
            }
        }
        
        var link = document.getElementById('downloadlink');
        link.href = makeTextFile(text);
        link.style.display = 'block';
    }, false);
})()
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody id="tbody">
        <tr>
            <td>1.1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2.1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="">
        <section class="module span12" style="top: 50px">
            <div class="module-body">
                <button type="button" class="btn-blue"
                style="top: 80px; right: 130px;" onclick="loadOutputs()">Load
                    Outputs</button>
                <button class="btn btn-blue" id="save"
                style="top: 80px; right: 130px;">Save</button>
                <a download="info.txt" id="downloadlink" style="display: block">Download</a>
                <div id="loadingElement" class="loaded">
                    <table>
                        <tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="row"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This time it loads function before HTML and it gives the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

Comment: I figured out now. Thanks!